# delphi - остановить idHTTP запрос на сервер до получения ответа

Tags: http, delphi-7, многопоточность, get, idhttp

Я реализую live-чат в своем проекте, который получает сообщения путем `GET` запрос на сервер. Сам сервер, в случае если новых сообщений не имеется, завершает запрос через 20 секунд. В делфи запрос вызывается из отдельного потока (который создается при переходе на страницу чата), чтобы не зависал интерфейс. Когда я ухожу из чата, из основного потока я вызываю код, представленный ниже, чтобы завершить поток:

```
if thread_chat <> nil then
begin
  thread_chat.Terminate;
  thread_chat := nil;
end;
```

Но так как таймаут сервера - 20 секунд, поток остается активным до получения ответа от сервера (внутри потока цикл `while not Terminated do`). Мне хотелось бы завершить поток не зависимо от того, получен ответ от сервера или же запрос все еще выполняется.

### Попытка #1

Изначально я рассматривал возможность использования `TerminateThread`, вызывая его как-то наподобие

```
TerminateThread(thread_chat.Handle, 0)
```

и первый раз поток убивался нормально, на второй раз прога полностью зависала. Так что я перешел к

### Попытка #2

Создал глобальную переменную `URL_HTTP: TIdHTTP` и получаю содержимое страницы с помощью этой функции:

```
function get_URL_Content(const Url: string): string;
var URL_stream: TStringStream;
begin
  URL_HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  URL_stream := TStringStream.Create(Result);
  URL_HTTP.Get(Url, URL_stream);
  if URL_HTTP <> nil then
  try
    URL_stream.Position := 0;
    Result := URL_stream.ReadString(URL_stream.Size);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(URL_HTTP);
    FreeAndNil(URL_stream);
  end;
end;
```

и когда я вне `thread_chat` вызываю данный код

```
if thread_guild_chat_action <> nil then
begin
  URL_HTTP.Disconnect;
  thread_chat.Terminate;
end;
```

я получаю ошибку доступа.

Больше я ничего не смог сделать. Как можно закрыть запрос до получения ответа?

Answer (score 1):

> Создал глобальную переменную URL_HTTP: TIdHTTP

Это очень плохо и из-за этого вы стреляете себе в ногу, когда вызывается `URL_HTTP.Disconnect` после `FreeAndNil(URL_HTTP)` (объект уже удален) или до `URL_HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil)` (объект еще не создан).

Минимальными усилиями можно попробовать решить проблему таким образом:

```
if thread_guild_chat_action <> nil then
begin
  if Assigned(URL_HTTP) then // проверка на nil
    URL_HTTP.Disconnect;
  thread_chat.Terminate;
end;
```

Это будет почти всегда работать, но вероятность того, что вы когда-нибудь получите в этом месте ошибку доступа, останется.